# Ucanaccess is too slow

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess, jackcess

I have correctly added all the necessary JARS:

- Ucanaccess 3.0.4
- commons-lang-2.6
- commons-logging-1.1.1
- hsqldbd
- jackcess-2.1.3

My database is 100MB. While using only Jacksess, the same query takes 4-5 seconds, while this one takes about 1-2 minutes. I made some research and found out that Ucanaccess mirors the whole database. How can I disable that? Or is it necessary?

I also tried with parameters (memory, singleConnection, skipIndexes) but it didn't change anything.

I have to use UcanAccess because I want to use JasperReports. And for this I need a valid connection.

My code:

```
        try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://P:/myDatabase.accdb";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "", "");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        String query =
                "Select * from REQ_ACQ_ACQUISITIONS";


        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            int numColumns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            for ( int i = 1 ; i <= numColumns ; i++ ) {
                if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
                String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It is slow when executing:
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "", "");

Comment: Is `P:` a mapped drive letter for a network share? If so, can you try copying the database file to your local hard drive and opening it there to compare execution times?

Comment: Dear Gord,  it is indeed a mapped drive. But I tried locally and the response was exactly the same ( even slower if possible?)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that this is not truly the "connection time" but the time of the very first connection in the whole JVM life. So it's a startup time, something like a database startup time. All the following connections will be istantaneous. There are several approches to drammatically reduce the time of the very first connection. The easiest one is to build a filter database that links, as external tables, the only tables you need for your reports.

Comment: Hello Jamadei, how would you go on doing that? Do you think it has to be done in *Ucanaccess*?

Comment: No, absolutely, it works already. You just have to create (using ms access) a new access database and the linked tables  which must point to the original ones in the original database (see external data). Then you have to connect, through ucanaccess,the newly created database.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to multiply the database - especially since I don't know exactly how many tables I  am going to use ( maybe all of them ). Plus I can't install Access on this ( business ) computer. Let's say I would like to resolve the problem only via java.

Comment: @pathat0r - Responses to some of your comments: *"I don't know exactly how many tables I am going to use ( maybe all of them )."* Then you'll need to mirror all of them. *"Plus I can't install Access on this ( business ) computer."* So you have a real business requirement to use an Access database but you cannot use the Access software? That's... unfortunate. *"I have to use UcanAccess because I want to use JasperReports."* Not necessarily. You could also use Java 7 and Java's own JDBC-ODBC Bridge, or you could use some other (commercial?) JDBC driver or JDBC-ODBC Bridge solution.

Comment: `So it's a startup time, something like a database startup time.` Yup...I happens as you said... The very first connection is slow but the rest of the time (as long as we keep a reference the opened connection) the DB connection/transactions are pretty fast

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a similar issue but mostly because throughout my code, I never closed my connections after running queries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Java's [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is your friend.